# how to pass data from parsed text file and insert the values to ObservableList in javafx?

Tags: java, csv, javafx, tableview, observablelist

content of text file

```
    gr.spinellis.ckjm.ClassVisitor 13 2 0 14 74 34 2 9

    gr.spinellis.ckjm.ClassMetricsContainer 3 1 0 3 18 0 2 2

    gr.spinellis.ckjm.MetricsFilter 7 1 0 6 30 11 2 5

    gr.spinellis.ckjm.PrintPlainResults 2 1 0 2 8 0 1 2

    gr.spinellis.ckjm.MethodVisitor 11 2 0 21 40 0 1 8

    gr.spinellis.ckjm.CkjmOutputHandler 1 1 0 1 1 0 3 1
```

i am parsing text file and then i want to view the values in organized way ,

the parsing works well , now i want to put the values i get from text file to TableView .

this is my code

```
package show;
   import java.io.BufferedReader;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
   import java.nio.file.Files;
   import java.nio.file.Path;
   import java.nio.file.Paths;
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.List;
   import javafx.application.Application;
   import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
   import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
   import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
   import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
   import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
   import javafx.event.Event;
   import javafx.event.EventHandler;
   import javafx.scene.Group;
   import javafx.scene.Scene;
   import javafx.scene.chart.PieChart;
   import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
   import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
   import javafx.scene.control.TableView.TableViewSelectionModel;
   import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
   import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
   import javafx.stage.Stage;

       public class show_TableView extends Application {

        public TableView < Metrics > tableView = new TableView<Metrics>();
       private ObservableList< Metrics > dataList =   FXCollections.observableArrayList(

       // /do something like this  new Metrics(name,WMC,DIT,NOC ,CBO,RFC,LCOM , Ce, NPM),
       // i want to add Metrics ADDED DYNAMICALLY after file is parsed

       );

         ObservableList<PieChart.Data> pieChartData = FXCollections
                       .observableArrayList(
                               new PieChart.Data("CBO", m.getCBO()),
                               new PieChart.Data("Ce", m.getCe()),
                               new PieChart.Data("DIT", m.getDIT()),
                               new PieChart.Data("LCOM", m.getLCOM()),
                               new PieChart.Data("NOC", m.getNOC()),
                               new PieChart.Data("NPM", m.getNPM()),
                               new PieChart.Data("WMC", m.getWMC()));
               c.setData(pieChartData);







         public static void main(String[] args) {
             launch(args);
         }

    @Override
   public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

       primaryStage.setTitle("java-buddy.blogspot.com");
       Group root = new Group();

       TableColumn name = new TableColumn("name");
       name.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, String>(
               "name"));

       TableColumn WMCCol = new TableColumn("WMC");
       WMCCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>(
               "WMC"));

       TableColumn DITCol = new TableColumn("DIT");
       DITCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>(
               "DIT"));

       TableColumn NOCCol = new TableColumn("NOC");
       NOCCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>(
               "NOC"));
       TableColumn CBOCol = new TableColumn("CBO");
       CBOCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>(
               "CBO"));
       TableColumn RFCCol = new TableColumn("RFC");
       RFCCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>(
               "RFC"));
       TableColumn LCOMCol = new TableColumn("LCOM");
       LCOMCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>(
               "LCOM"));
       TableColumn ceCol = new TableColumn("Ca");
       ceCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>(
               "ce"));
       TableColumn NPMCol = new TableColumn("NPM");
       NPMCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>(
               "NPM"));

       primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 200, 200));
       primaryStage.show();

       List<Metrics> metric = readMetricFromCSV("C:\\Users\\pavi\\Desktop\\11.txt");
       // let's print all the metric read from CSV file
       for (Metrics m : metric) {
           System.out.println(m);

       }

       tableView.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(metric));
       tableView.getColumns().addAll(name, WMCCol, DITCol, NOCCol, CBOCol,
               RFCCol, LCOMCol, ceCol, NPMCol);

       VBox vBox = new VBox();
       vBox.setMaxSize(600, 600);
       vBox.setSpacing(10);
       PieChart c = new PieChart();
       tableView.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<Event>() {

           @Override
           public void handle(Event event) {
               c.setData(FXCollections.emptyObservableList());
               TableViewSelectionModel<Metrics> tableViewSelectionModel = tableView
                       .selectionModelProperty().get();
               Metrics m = tableViewSelectionModel.getSelectedItem();
               if(m==null){
                   return;
               }
               ObservableList<PieChart.Data> pieChartData = FXCollections
                       .observableArrayList(
                               new PieChart.Data("CBO", m.getCBO()),
                               new PieChart.Data("Ce", m.getCe()),
                               new PieChart.Data("DIT", m.getDIT()),
                               new PieChart.Data("LCOM", m.getLCOM()),
                               new PieChart.Data("NOC", m.getNOC()),
                               new PieChart.Data("NPM", m.getNPM()),
                               new PieChart.Data("WMC", m.getWMC()));
               c.setData(pieChartData);
           }
       });
       vBox.getChildren().add(tableView);
       vBox.getChildren().add(c);

       root.getChildren().add(vBox);

   }

   public List<Metrics> readMetricFromCSV(String fileName) {

       List<Metrics> metricsss = new ArrayList<>();

       Path pathToFile = Paths.get(fileName);
       // create an instance of BufferedReader
       // using try with resource, Java 7 feature to close resources
       try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(pathToFile,
               StandardCharsets.US_ASCII)) {
           // read the first line from the text file
           String line = br.readLine();
           while (line != null && !line.isEmpty()) { // loop until all lines
                                                       // are read
               String[] attributes = line.split(" "); // the file, using a
                                                       // comma as the
                                                       // delimiter
               Metrics valueOfMetric = createMetric(attributes);
               metricsss.add(valueOfMetric); // adding metric into ArrayList
               // skip empty line
               // line.isEmpty() || line.trim().equals("") ||
               // line.trim().equals("\n"))
               br.readLine();
               line = br.readLine();
           }

       } catch (IOException ioe) {
           ioe.printStackTrace();
       }

       return metricsss;
   }
         private   Metrics createMetric(String[] metadata) {
           String name = metadata[0];
           int WMC = Integer.parseInt(metadata[1]);
           int DIT = Integer.parseInt(metadata[2]);
           int NOC = Integer.parseInt(metadata[3]);
           int CBO = Integer.parseInt(metadata[4]);
           int RFC = Integer.parseInt(metadata[5]);
           int LCOM= Integer.parseInt(metadata[6]);
           int Ce  = Integer.parseInt(metadata[7]);
           int NPM = Integer.parseInt(metadata[8]);
           return new Metrics(name,WMC,DIT,NOC,CBO,RFC,LCOM,Ce,NPM);//,cc
       }


         public class Metrics {

           private String name;
           private int WMC;
           private int DIT;
           private int NOC;
           private int CBO;
           private int RFC;
           private int LCOM;
           private int Ce;
           private int NPM;

           public Metrics( String name,int WMC,int DIT,int NOC,int CBO,int RFC,int LCOM, int Ce, int NPM) {

               this.name = name;
               this.WMC = WMC;
               this.DIT = DIT;
               this.NOC = NOC;
               this.CBO = CBO;
               this.RFC = RFC;
               this.LCOM = LCOM;
               this.Ce = Ce;
               this.NPM = NPM;
           }

           public String getName() {
               return name;
           }

           public void setName(String name) {
               this.name = name;
           }

           public int getWMC() {
               return WMC;
           }

           public void setWMC(int WMC) {
               this.WMC = WMC;
           }

           public int getDIT() {
               return DIT;
           }

           public void setDIT(int DIT) {
               this.DIT = DIT;
           }

           public int getNOC() {
               return NOC;
           }

           public void setNOC(int NOC) {
               this.NOC = NOC;
           }

           public int getCBO() {
               return CBO;
           }

           public void setCBO(int CBO) {
               this.CBO = CBO;
           }

           public int getRFC() {
               return RFC;
           }

           public void setRFC(int RFC) {
               this.RFC = RFC;
           }

           public int getLCOM() {
               return LCOM;
           }

           public void setLCOM(int LCOM) {
               this.LCOM = LCOM;
           }

           public int getCe() {
               return Ce;
           }

           public void setCe(int ce) {
               Ce = ce;
           }

           public int getNPM() {
               return NPM;
           }

           public void setNPM(int NPM) {
               this.NPM = NPM;
           }


       }




       }
```

Comment: @James_D   the main problem is how to inserting value to   private ObservableList< Metrics > dataList =   FXCollections.observableArrayList()

Comment: `tableView.getItems().addAll(metric)` doesn't work? (Or just `dataList.addAll(metric)`?)

Comment: No it didn't work @James_D

Comment: What does "it didn't work" mean? Compile error? Exception? Nothing happens at all? I assume you put that line after `List<Metrics> metric = readMetricFromCSV(...);`.

Comment: Yes ,i put it after  List<Metrics> metric = readMetricFromCSV(...); but Nothing happens at all @James_D

Comment: Your `System.out.println(...)` shows that the list has some elements in it? Can you edit the question to include the call to `tableView.getItems().addAll(metric);`? (While you're there, please can you clean up the formatting, so it is easier to read the code?)

Comment: @James_D  sorry, i just clicked run instead of clean and build ,please post it as an answer so i can accept it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

[Pie Chart java example](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/pie-chart.htm#CIHFDADD)

```
tableView.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(metric));//added
```

I have added above line of code to create observaleList using list

```
 br.readLine();//removed here this read extraline 
String line1=null;
// read the first line from the text file
String line = br.readLine();                 
while (line != null) {
```

above condition is worng what if line is empty ? I have changed this too.(sorry for not explaing I dont know that much english)

```
    @Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    primaryStage.setTitle("java-buddy.blogspot.com");
    Group root = new Group();

    TableColumn name = new TableColumn("name");
    name.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, String>(
            "name"));

    TableColumn WMCCol = new TableColumn("WMC");
    WMCCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>(
            "WMC"));

    TableColumn DITCol = new TableColumn("DIT");
    DITCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>(
            "DIT"));

    TableColumn NOCCol = new TableColumn("NOC");
    NOCCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>(
            "NOC"));
    TableColumn CBOCol = new TableColumn("CBO");
    CBOCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>(
            "CBO"));
    TableColumn RFCCol = new TableColumn("RFC");
    RFCCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>(
            "RFC"));
    TableColumn LCOMCol = new TableColumn("LCOM");
    LCOMCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>(
            "LCOM"));
    TableColumn ceCol = new TableColumn("Ca");
    ceCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>(
            "ce"));
    TableColumn NPMCol = new TableColumn("NPM");
    NPMCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>(
            "NPM"));

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 200, 200));
    primaryStage.show();

    List<Metrics> metric = readMetricFromCSV("C:\\Users\\pavi\\Desktop\\11.txt");
    // let's print all the metric read from CSV file
    for (Metrics m : metric) {
        System.out.println(m);

    }

    tableView.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(metric));
    tableView.getColumns().addAll(name, WMCCol, DITCol, NOCCol, CBOCol,
            RFCCol, LCOMCol, ceCol, NPMCol);

    VBox vBox = new VBox();
    vBox.setMaxSize(600, 600);
    vBox.setSpacing(10);
    PieChart c = new PieChart();
    tableView.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<Event>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(Event event) {
            c.setData(FXCollections.emptyObservableList());
            TableViewSelectionModel<Metrics> tableViewSelectionModel = tableView
                    .selectionModelProperty().get();
            Metrics m = tableViewSelectionModel.getSelectedItem();
            if(m==null){
                return;
            }
            ObservableList<PieChart.Data> pieChartData = FXCollections
                    .observableArrayList(
                            new PieChart.Data("CBO", m.getCBO()),
                            new PieChart.Data("Ce", m.getCe()),
                            new PieChart.Data("DIT", m.getDIT()),
                            new PieChart.Data("LCOM", m.getLCOM()),
                            new PieChart.Data("NOC", m.getNOC()),
                            new PieChart.Data("NPM", m.getNPM()),
                            new PieChart.Data("WMC", m.getWMC()));
            c.setData(pieChartData);
        }
    });
    vBox.getChildren().add(tableView);
    vBox.getChildren().add(c);

    root.getChildren().add(vBox);

}

public List<Metrics> readMetricFromCSV(String fileName) {

    List<Metrics> metricsss = new ArrayList<>();

    Path pathToFile = Paths.get(fileName);
    // create an instance of BufferedReader
    // using try with resource, Java 7 feature to close resources
    try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(pathToFile,
            StandardCharsets.US_ASCII)) {
        // read the first line from the text file
        String line = br.readLine();
        while (line != null && !line.isEmpty()) { // loop until all lines
                                                    // are read
            String[] attributes = line.split(" "); // the file, using a
                                                    // comma as the
                                                    // delimiter
            Metrics valueOfMetric = createMetric(attributes);
            metricsss.add(valueOfMetric); // adding metric into ArrayList
            // skip empty line
            // line.isEmpty() || line.trim().equals("") ||
            // line.trim().equals("\n"))
            br.readLine();
            line = br.readLine();
        }

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }

    return metricsss;
}
```

for charts we need create data set to pieChart.setData(pieChartData);
Reff the like bellow image you ll understand

```
ObservableList<PieChart.Data> pieChartData = FXCollections
                    .observableArrayList(
                            new PieChart.Data("CBO", m.getCBO()),
                            new PieChart.Data("Ce", m.getCe()),
                            new PieChart.Data("DIT", m.getDIT()),
                            new PieChart.Data("LCOM", m.getLCOM()),
                            new PieChart.Data("NOC", m.getNOC()),
                            new PieChart.Data("NPM", m.getNPM()),
                            new PieChart.Data("WMC", m.getWMC()));
            c.setData(pieChartData);
```

Comment: but why i cant do the same for pie chart  tableView.getItems().addAll(metric) ;
 pieChart.getItems().addAll(metric) ;

Comment: how can i show data of each row in the pie chart when selected ?

Comment: thanks so much , i have small problem when i compile the source code , which is ObservableList is not working in this project?!

Comment: how can u say that ? any error on console, after runing code you'll see a table view window maximize the window and click on a row you ll see pie chart AND no problem in the above code.replay me with exact problem

Comment: the table view window is not shown properly , i have updated the code can you tell me what want wrong ?

Comment: change Group root=new Group() to VBox root=new VBox() and primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 200, 200)); to primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root)); and remove this line  vBox.setMaxSize(600, 600); and add this lines above(this line root.getChildren().add(vBox);)HBox boxc = new HBox();
  vBox.prefWidthProperty().bind(root.prefWidthProperty());
  boxc.setManaged(true);
  boxc.getChildren().addAll(tableView, c);
  vBox.getChildren().add(boxc);

Comment: i tried to combine but for some reasons can't run it even after adding the changes ,please do me a favor and send the code to email mdsavs@mailinator.com

Comment: [check this like i just posted that code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32858244/no-error-then-why-observablelist-is-not-working-in-this-project/32871638#32871638) 
if still you got problem i ll mail that java file

Comment: yes i still have same problem please do me a favor and send java file to email mdsavs@mailinator.com i will run it in different IDE and see how it goes .

Comment: i have sent mail and send me. what error u r getting what is that problem?