# no error then why ObservableList is not working in this project?

Tags: java, csv, text-files, javafx-8, observablelist

i saw this project in previous answer and I tried to run it but it didn't 
[how to pass data from parsed text file and insert the values to ObservableList in javafx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32849589/how-to-pass-data-from-parsed-text-file-and-insert-the-values-to-observablelist-i/32850500#32850500)

data  inputted from text file to table view and then piechart JAVAFX, everything was work except the pie chart I am trying to get data from table view to pie chart, i have done after few edits I can't run it anymore

the problem in     ObservableList pieChartData = FXCollections
                            .observableArrayList()

this is the code

```
    package show;
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
    import java.nio.file.Files;
    import java.nio.file.Path;
    import java.nio.file.Paths;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
    import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
    import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
    import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
    import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
    import javafx.event.Event;
    import javafx.event.EventHandler;
    import javafx.scene.Group;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.chart.PieChart;
    import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
    import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
    import javafx.scene.control.TableView.TableViewSelectionModel;
    import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
    import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;

        public class show_TableView extends Application {

         public TableView < Metrics > tableView = new TableView<Metrics>();
        private ObservableList< Metrics > dataList =   FXCollections.observableArrayList(

        // /do something like this  new Metrics(name,WMC,DIT,NOC ,CBO,RFC,LCOM , Ce, NPM),
        // i want to add Metrics ADDED DYNAMICALLY after file is parsed

        );

          ObservableList<PieChart.Data> pieChartData = FXCollections
                        .observableArrayList(
                                new PieChart.Data("CBO", m.getCBO()),
                                new PieChart.Data("Ce", m.getCe()),
                                new PieChart.Data("DIT", m.getDIT()),
                                new PieChart.Data("LCOM", m.getLCOM()),
                                new PieChart.Data("NOC", m.getNOC()),
                                new PieChart.Data("NPM", m.getNPM()),
                                new PieChart.Data("WMC", m.getWMC()));
                c.setData(pieChartData);







          public static void main(String[] args) {
              launch(args);
          }

     @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        primaryStage.setTitle("java-buddy.blogspot.com");
        Group root = new Group();

        TableColumn name = new TableColumn("name");
        name.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, String>(
                "name"));

        TableColumn WMCCol = new TableColumn("WMC");
        WMCCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>(
                "WMC"));

        TableColumn DITCol = new TableColumn("DIT");
        DITCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>(
                "DIT"));

        TableColumn NOCCol = new TableColumn("NOC");
        NOCCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>(
                "NOC"));
        TableColumn CBOCol = new TableColumn("CBO");
        CBOCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>(
                "CBO"));
        TableColumn RFCCol = new TableColumn("RFC");
        RFCCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>(
                "RFC"));
        TableColumn LCOMCol = new TableColumn("LCOM");
        LCOMCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>(
                "LCOM"));
        TableColumn ceCol = new TableColumn("Ca");
        ceCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>(
                "ce"));
        TableColumn NPMCol = new TableColumn("NPM");
        NPMCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>(
                "NPM"));

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 200, 200));
        primaryStage.show();

        List<Metrics> metric = readMetricFromCSV("C:\\Users\\pavi\\Desktop\\11.txt");
        // let's print all the metric read from CSV file
        for (Metrics m : metric) {
            System.out.println(m);

        }

        tableView.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(metric));
        tableView.getColumns().addAll(name, WMCCol, DITCol, NOCCol, CBOCol,
                RFCCol, LCOMCol, ceCol, NPMCol);

        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.setMaxSize(600, 600);
        vBox.setSpacing(10);
        PieChart c = new PieChart();
        tableView.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<Event>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(Event event) {
                c.setData(FXCollections.emptyObservableList());
                TableViewSelectionModel<Metrics> tableViewSelectionModel = tableView
                        .selectionModelProperty().get();
                Metrics m = tableViewSelectionModel.getSelectedItem();
                if(m==null){
                    return;
                }
                ObservableList<PieChart.Data> pieChartData = FXCollections
                        .observableArrayList(
                                new PieChart.Data("CBO", m.getCBO()),
                                new PieChart.Data("Ce", m.getCe()),
                                new PieChart.Data("DIT", m.getDIT()),
                                new PieChart.Data("LCOM", m.getLCOM()),
                                new PieChart.Data("NOC", m.getNOC()),
                                new PieChart.Data("NPM", m.getNPM()),
                                new PieChart.Data("WMC", m.getWMC()));
                c.setData(pieChartData);
            }
        });
        vBox.getChildren().add(tableView);
        vBox.getChildren().add(c);

        root.getChildren().add(vBox);

    }

    public List<Metrics> readMetricFromCSV(String fileName) {

        List<Metrics> metricsss = new ArrayList<>();

        Path pathToFile = Paths.get(fileName);
        // create an instance of BufferedReader
        // using try with resource, Java 7 feature to close resources
        try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(pathToFile,
                StandardCharsets.US_ASCII)) {
            // read the first line from the text file
            String line = br.readLine();
            while (line != null && !line.isEmpty()) { // loop until all lines
                                                        // are read
                String[] attributes = line.split(" "); // the file, using a
                                                        // comma as the
                                                        // delimiter
                Metrics valueOfMetric = createMetric(attributes);
                metricsss.add(valueOfMetric); // adding metric into ArrayList
                // skip empty line
                // line.isEmpty() || line.trim().equals("") ||
                // line.trim().equals("\n"))
                br.readLine();
                line = br.readLine();
            }

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

        return metricsss;
    }
          private   Metrics createMetric(String[] metadata) {
            String name = metadata[0];
            int WMC = Integer.parseInt(metadata[1]);
            int DIT = Integer.parseInt(metadata[2]);
            int NOC = Integer.parseInt(metadata[3]);
            int CBO = Integer.parseInt(metadata[4]);
            int RFC = Integer.parseInt(metadata[5]);
            int LCOM= Integer.parseInt(metadata[6]);
            int Ce  = Integer.parseInt(metadata[7]);
            int NPM = Integer.parseInt(metadata[8]);
            return new Metrics(name,WMC,DIT,NOC,CBO,RFC,LCOM,Ce,NPM);//,cc
        }


          public class Metrics {

            private String name;
            private int WMC;
            private int DIT;
            private int NOC;
            private int CBO;
            private int RFC;
            private int LCOM;
            private int Ce;
            private int NPM;

            public Metrics( String name,int WMC,int DIT,int NOC,int CBO,int RFC,int LCOM, int Ce, int NPM) {

                this.name = name;
                this.WMC = WMC;
                this.DIT = DIT;
                this.NOC = NOC;
                this.CBO = CBO;
                this.RFC = RFC;
                this.LCOM = LCOM;
                this.Ce = Ce;
                this.NPM = NPM;
            }

            public String getName() {
                return name;
            }

            public void setName(String name) {
                this.name = name;
            }

            public int getWMC() {
                return WMC;
            }

            public void setWMC(int WMC) {
                this.WMC = WMC;
            }

            public int getDIT() {
                return DIT;
            }

            public void setDIT(int DIT) {
                this.DIT = DIT;
            }

            public int getNOC() {
                return NOC;
            }

            public void setNOC(int NOC) {
                this.NOC = NOC;
            }

            public int getCBO() {
                return CBO;
            }

            public void setCBO(int CBO) {
                this.CBO = CBO;
            }

            public int getRFC() {
                return RFC;
            }

            public void setRFC(int RFC) {
                this.RFC = RFC;
            }

            public int getLCOM() {
                return LCOM;
            }

            public void setLCOM(int LCOM) {
                this.LCOM = LCOM;
            }

            public int getCe() {
                return Ce;
            }

            public void setCe(int ce) {
                Ce = ce;
            }

            public int getNPM() {
                return NPM;
            }

            public void setNPM(int NPM) {
                this.NPM = NPM;
            }


        }




        }
```

text file content

```
    gr.spinellis.ckjm.ClassVisitor 13 2 0 14 74 34 2 9

    gr.spinellis.ckjm.ClassMetricsContainer 3 1 0 3 18 0 2 2

    gr.spinellis.ckjm.MetricsFilter 7 1 0 6 30 11 2 5

    gr.spinellis.ckjm.PrintPlainResults 2 1 0 2 8 0 1 2

    gr.spinellis.ckjm.MethodVisitor 11 2 0 21 40 0 1 8

    gr.spinellis.ckjm.CkjmOutputHandler 1 1 0 1 1 0 3 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No Problem with ObservableList pieChartData = FXCollections .observableArrayList() this is an empty arryList.[image]

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    primaryStage.setTitle("java-buddy.blogspot.com");
    VBox root = new VBox();

    TableColumn name = new TableColumn("name");
    name.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, String>(
            "name"));

    TableColumn WMCCol = new TableColumn("WMC");
    WMCCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>(
            "WMC"));

    TableColumn DITCol = new TableColumn("DIT");
    DITCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>(
            "DIT"));

    TableColumn NOCCol = new TableColumn("NOC");
    NOCCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>(
            "NOC"));
    TableColumn CBOCol = new TableColumn("CBO");
    CBOCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>(
            "CBO"));
    TableColumn RFCCol = new TableColumn("RFC");
    RFCCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>(
            "RFC"));
    TableColumn LCOMCol = new TableColumn("LCOM");
    LCOMCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>(
            "LCOM"));
    TableColumn ceCol = new TableColumn("Ca");
    ceCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>(
            "ce"));
    TableColumn NPMCol = new TableColumn("NPM");
    NPMCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>(
            "NPM"));

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    primaryStage.show();

    List<Metrics> metric = readMetricFromCSV("C:\\Users\\pavi\\Desktop\\11.txt");
    // let's print all the metric read from CSV file
    for (Metrics m : metric) {
        System.out.println(m);

    }

    tableView.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(metric));
    tableView.getColumns().addAll(name, WMCCol, DITCol, NOCCol, CBOCol,
            RFCCol, LCOMCol, ceCol, NPMCol);

    VBox vBox = new VBox();

    vBox.setSpacing(10);
    PieChart c = new PieChart();
    tableView.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<Event>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(Event event) {
            c.setData(FXCollections.emptyObservableList());
            TableViewSelectionModel<Metrics> tableViewSelectionModel = tableView
                    .selectionModelProperty().get();
            Metrics m = tableViewSelectionModel.getSelectedItem();
            if (m == null) {
                return;
            }
            ObservableList<PieChart.Data> pieChartData = FXCollections
                    .observableArrayList(
                            new PieChart.Data("CBO", m.getCBO()),
                            new PieChart.Data("Ce", m.getCe()),
                            new PieChart.Data("DIT", m.getDIT()),
                            new PieChart.Data("LCOM", m.getLCOM()),
                            new PieChart.Data("NOC", m.getNOC()),
                            new PieChart.Data("NPM", m.getNPM()),
                            new PieChart.Data("WMC", m.getWMC()));
            c.setData(pieChartData);
        }
    });
    HBox boxc = new HBox();
    vBox.prefWidthProperty().bind(root.prefWidthProperty());
    boxc.setManaged(true);
    boxc.getChildren().addAll(tableView, c);
    vBox.getChildren().add(boxc);

    root.getChildren().add(vBox);

}
```

i hope this will solve your problem